# C++ Check Data Type in Class Function

Tags: c++, validation

I know there are several answers similar to this question already but I think my lack of experience in C++ is preventing me from understanding them fully.

**Problem**: I have an assignment where I need the user to enter a value which should be of type 'double'. I then need to pass that user input into a custom method for a class I created and have the method validate that this input is indeed a 'double'.

I saw several posts where people validated the data type right after it was entered using a `while` loop and the `cin` operator. This doesn't help me because I need to validate the data type in the method.

Here is what I have so far:

**Main.cpp:**

```
...
int main() {

    string name;
    double gpa;   // value that should be validated

    cout << Enter GPA: ";
    cin >> gpa;

    myClass student_1;
    student_1.validateGPA(gpa); 

    return 0;
}
```

**myClass.h**

...

```
template <class validation>
void validateGPA(validation);
```

**myClass.cpp**

...

```
template <class validation>
string myClass::validateGPA(validation gpa) {
    return typeid(newGPA).name();
}
```

As written currently I am receiving this Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall myClass::validateGPA<double>(double)" (??$validateGPA@N@myClass@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function _main    GPA_Assignment  C:\Users\josep\source\repos\ccv\GPA\GPA\GPA_Assignment.obj  1
```

Without templating the function, the program ran but no matter what I entered at the prompt, the validation method always returned 'double'. I am assuming that is bc of how I declared the gpa varaible in the beginning, but I don't know a better way.

Thoughts!??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: The linker error you're getting is indeed related to it being a templated function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). As far as the function returning incorrect values, note that the function's argument is `gpa` but you return `typeid(newGPA)`. what's `newGPA`? ETA: Not that it's going to be relevant because `main` guarantees that whatever the user inputs, you hand a `double` to the `validateGPA` function.

Comment: You don't "check data types" in C++. You validate user input. You say `double gpa`, it's `double`, there's nothing to check.

Comment: @NathanPierson  `newGPA` is the gpa variable, just a transposition error putting the question up

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  What if the user enters a string instead of a double? When i do that in my code it works. The code prints the string out but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you want to defer input validation to the actual class itself, I suggest storing the user input in a `std::string` instead of a `double` in `main` and then doing the type conversion in a class method.

Comment: User input cannot magically change the type of `gpa`. The user can pound on the keyboard all day long and `gpa` will stay `double`. Variables in C++ don't change their types. What can happen depending on user input is that `cin >> gpa` can either *succeed* or *fail*, and you are supposed to check *that*.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  Maybe the better way to phrase this would be how do I validate user input in the method instead of the main

Comment: @NathanPierson  That sounds like it may work. If the user entered a string and I tried to convert to a double would I receive some error that may help or would it just convert it to double no issue?

Comment: You can do what you want in any place in the code you want. You just need to check the right thing. `typeid` isn't one.

Comment: Maybe try search. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+input+double+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) help?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I have already spent a couple hours playing that search game. You'll notice that most of the result (that I can make sense of) use a CIN validation technique, which I mentioned in my question does not work for me'

Comment: "does not work for me" It doesn't make a lot of sense. You can do `cin >>` in a method. Why would it not work for you?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I guess my confusion is that I didn't think I could pass cin through the method. But reading your comment it sounds like maybe I should be calling cin from the method and then validate there. Does that sound like a good solution?

Comment: `cin` is global, there's no need to pass it. It's an OK solution. What would you do if  the input doesn't validate?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I think I have it working using cin in the method. If it doesn't validate I just need to return a message saying that it was invalid. Thanks for the help, I think by calling cin in the method I can use the user validation examples here on stack and move forward!  This has been a big headache this morning!

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is an input stream. To get formatted data from input, you can use [the operator it defines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt): `>>`. If you put the input stream on the left hand side and a variable that has a type that it recognizes on the right hand side, `cin` will read to the end of its input and try to parse that into whatever data type is on the right hand side. Lucky for you, the operator does support `double`. Therefore, to read the input (a string) and convert it into a decimal number (a `double`), you can just write

```
double converted_number;
cin >> converted_number;
```

According to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate), you can validate the formatted input by checking the value of `cin.rdstate()`. Let's add that.

```cpp
double converted_number;
cin >> converted_number;

if(cin.rdstate() != goodbit) {
    cout << "A decimal number was expected, but an error occurred.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure to include the `ios` header at the beginning of your file if you haven't already.

`#include <ios>`

The error comes from the linker. It stems from the way you define your function template. You don't need it to be a template though. Just use a regular function. I feel the explanation for that is outside the scope of this question, so I'll just leave it at that.